# Stripe subscription data array index

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement a webhook for stripe .
Lets say i do

`event_json = json.loads(request.body)`

then i get the data i need at

```
event_json['data']['object']['subscriptions']['data'][0]['id']
```

the thing is  i am new to subscription does the array index "0" here change on every subscription?

part of the response is shown below

```
 {
        u'object': u'event',
        u'pending_webhooks': 1,
        u'created': 1486550453,
        u'type': u'customer.created',
        u'livemode': False,
        u'request': u'req_A52yftxLoyXcW6',
        u'data': {
            u'object': {
                u'subscriptions': {
                    u'has_more': False,
                    u'total_count': 1,
                    u'object': u'list',
                    u'data': [
                        {...
                         },
                         'id':'val',...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object) may have more than one [subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#subscription_object), which is why the [`subscriptions`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object-subscriptions) attribute is a [list object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#pagination-object).

If you only create one subscription per customer in the first place, then you can safely assume that the list will only ever contain one element (with index 0).

If it's possible for your customers to have more than one subscription, then you will have to manage this appropriately. List objects always contain results in reverse chronological order, i.e. the most recent subscription will be the first element in the list.